# Is there an easier way to reset states in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, state

My React app has a form to add a new product and each product has a number of properties. When the product is added I redirect the user to the saved products page, and they can edit any saved products. I've run into some (not major) issues with the states. In some areas when editing, the state displays another products attributes because it has not been updated.

I want to clear the state so that if a product attribute's state isn't updated it is simply an empty string. Right now I'm doing this:

```
const resetStates = () => {
    setName("");
    setDescription("");
    setPrice(null);
}
```

These are only some of the states being used, so it's cumbersome to have to reset all of them like this. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Potentially you can simply pass a new key to the component - which will cause the old one to be unmounted and the new one to be mounted with a fresh state. See this post for some more info: https://www.nikgraf.com/blog/using-reacts-key-attribute-to-remount-a-component

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate the state properties into a single object, like class components' state.

```
[formContent, setFormContent] = useState({name:'',desc:'',price: null});


const resetStates = ()=> {
    setFormContent({name: '', desc: '', price: null});
}
```

However the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables) seem to slightly prefer the separate state variables over a single object, since unlike `this.setState` updating a state variable using hooks, replaces its value.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if you need to reset the state, it indicates that you did something wrong.
The easiest way is to use the key property.
Like`<Product key={product.id} />`
When key changes, we will have a completely new Product component.
Make sure that you are unmounting components that store some old data, in that way, you don't need any reset state.

Comment: Using a key is the correct answer, but I don’t know why you prefaced it with “it usually means you did something wrong”. There’s lots of valid reasons to use a key to reset state, the most common one that comes to the top of my head is quickly and simply resetting a form component. It's here in the react docs: https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#option-2-resetting-state-with-a-key

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I mean that if you reset the state inside a component with setSate('') usually means that you do something wrong.